# react value is undefined when the value is clearly not empty

Tags: reactjs

```
<div className="controls">
  <i className="fas fa-play" value='work' onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}></i>
  <audio loop autoPlay></audio>
</div>
```

I am stupid, why is this not working.

Answer (score 1):

`i` elements have no `value` property, they have `textContent` and `innerHTML`, but no `value`. `value` is only for form elements. The `value` attribute you have on `i` is an invalid attribute, and isn't reflected by a property. You *could* use `e.target.getAttribute("value")`, but `value` would still be invalid.

With more context, we might be able to give you a more React-specific answer (you probably have an in-scope variable containing the value you could just use directly), but in the absense of more context, here's a baseline answer:

You can use a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and access that value either with `e.target.getAttribute("data-value")`:

```
<div className="controls">
  <i className="fas fa-play" data-value='work' onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.getAttribute("data-value"))}></i>
  <audio loop autoPlay></audio>
</div>
```

...or with [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) (`e.target.dataset.value`):

```
<div className="controls">
  <i className="fas fa-play" data-value='work' onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.dataset.value)}></i>
  <audio loop autoPlay></audio>
</div>
```